# codeigniter and fpdf code blockin during pdf output

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

i have a big problem with fpdf

in my page i have a lot of code and at the end i create a pdf file with this sample:

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
```

the result is that only the creatioin of pdf are make and the other code no !

first the code of the sample is:

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
//ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
```

like this the code before is execute without problem but not the pdf and i receive this on browser:

```
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

can you help me ?
im newbie with fpdf libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because your php code has **already outputted** some data to the browser.
Check that your php do not write any data to the browser yet ( except for the headers ) before calling `$pdf->Output()`, thus avoiding sending unknown data that has a pdf binary data appended at the end.

the `ob_end_clean()` function call ensure that your script clean any previous output your php script could have made.

Comment: yes but i need to outputted some data into the browser ! can you help me ?

Comment: Then you need to put the data in the browser from another script that link to your pdf generating script, there is no other way

Comment: an echo tag is possible before the pdf function ?

Comment: no you have to create the pdf in a separate script from the one that is creating the pdf